# create a datapipeline with tags usinf boto.datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to create AWS datapipeline with tags.
We are using boto.datapipeline API for creating the datapipeline.
these tags are used to give read/write access to datapipeline users using IAM management

Please provide the code syntax to create a datapipeline with tags

Comment: This is not yet supported.. They are yet to integrate with the latest Data Pipeline API model. Whenever it is, you would be able to see it here: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The features you are asking about are very recent (released last week).  Here is the link that describes how to do that.. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-control-access-tags.html

To tag a pipeline: aws datapipeline create-pipeline --name "pipeline_name" --tags Key="environment",Value="production" Key="owner",Value="sales"

Before you can tag, you must opt-in by logging in as the 'account owner' a.k.a root account -  as these features are based on new Data Pipeline security model.

Comment: I need code to create datapipeline with tag using AWS boto API. API call to tag using create_datapipeline("mypipeline"). Using CLI I can do that but I need to write using AWS BOTO APi it in a script.